# Rotating a full-page floating figure landscape

Tags: floats, rotating, fullpage

I have a group of 4 tables (`tabularx`s) that are laid out in a 2x2 grid. **I'd like for them to take up a full page in landscape**, so naturally I turned to the `fltpage` package to get them to take up a full page. It works great, except there doesn't seem to be an option to put the full-page float in landscape. **Is there another package I could use in addition to or instead of `fltpage` to accomplish this?** I tried `hvfloat` but the `hvFloatEnv` environment doesn't appear to take any of the other positioning parameters that you can specify for the normal command.

Inside of these `tabularx`s, I use not only custom row types but also `\multirow` and `\multicolumn`, as well as `\rowcolor` and a macro that invokes inline musical notation from the `lyluatex` package. Due to the custom row types, I would rather not switch to another table package/type.

Additionally, I don't know exactly where this full-page float landscape page will fall and I'd like for it to stay 'floating'. There is an answer to another question on this site that recommends using `\afterpage`, but I am not sure where to put that instruction (inside or before the `\FPfigure` seems unlikely to work, since it needs to already be in landscape by the time that begins...) in this case.

Here is the basic setup (without the landscape rotation, obviously):

```
\begin{FPfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]
         \begin{tabularx}
             % Table 1 content
         \end{tabularx}
         \caption{Caption for Table 1}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[b]
         \begin{tabularx}
              % Table 2 content
         \end{tabularx}
         \caption{Caption for Table 2}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[t]
         \begin{tabularx}
             % Table 3 content
         \end{tabularx}
         \begin{tabularx}
             % Table 4 content
         \end{tabularx}
         \caption{Caption for Tables 3 & 4}
     \end{subfigure}
\end{FPfigure}
```

## Preamble

As requested, here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,
               titlepage,%twoside,
               openany
               ]{report}
\input{./TeX_files/defs/includes}
\input{./TeX_files/defs/defs}% Macros and variables used throughout the document
\input{./TeX_files/defs/colordefs}% Basically just a bunch of `\colorlet`s
\input{./Tex_files/tcolorboxtweaks}% Some macros I wrote that improve upon `tcolorbox`'s bounding box calculations (to include the box title even when it extends beyond the content box width) and to faciliate easy use of tcolorboxes as floats, using `fltfloat`
\input{./TeX_files/defs/figdefs}% Macros used for `\tabularx`s and floats
\input{./TeX_files/defs/musdefs}% Macros used for musical examples and for typesetting pitch class set names and numbers
\input{./TeX_files/defs/bfootdefs}% Used to fix the footnote issues I was having with `tcolorbox`, as well as some custom citation macros for citing the Bible inline or in footnotes and `hyperref` linking to my bibliography
\input{./TeX_files/defs/colpatext_defs}% Macros used in the visual score for the dramatic monologue. Speech bubble stuff and special box breaking and extension using `tcolorbox`, linguistic gloss tweaking for `covington`... etcetera.

% Variables defined in defs.tex that just control whether or not I want to skip the rendering of certain parts of the document. The reflection hasn't been written yet so that's why it's false.
\printabstracttrue
\printbodytrue
\printcolpatexttrue
\printreflectionfalse
\printappendicestrue
\printglossariestrue
\printindexestrue
\printbibtrue
```

The contents of `includes.tex`:

```
%%% MACRO UTILS %%%
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{xspace}
%\usepackage{catoptions}%,cmdstring}

\usepackage{intcalc}

%%% MISC %%%
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% SPACING %%%
\usepackage{setspace}

%%% FONTS, HEADINGS %%%
%\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{verse}

%%% FLOAT STUFF %%%
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%%% BOXES AND SUCH %%%
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,raster,breakable,fitting,hooks}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    positioning,
    arrows.meta,
    shapes.geometric,
    topaths,
    scopes,
    svg.path}
\usepackage[prefix=M]{xcolor-material}
\usepackage[cache=true,cachedir=./out/_minted-colpadif,section]{minted}
\setminted{%
    autogobble=true,breaklines=true,breakafter={,;},breakautoindent=true,%
    breakbefore={\\"},%
    bgcolor=white,fontfamily=tt,fontseries=auto,fontsize=auto,fontshape=auto,%
    linenos=true,numbers=both,numberfirstline=true,stepnumber=1,%
    samepage=false,%
    showspaces=true,showtabs=true,%
    style=default,texcl=false,texcomments=false,%
}


%%% TABULAR %%%
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

%%% MUSIC %%%
\usepackage{lyluatex}
%\usepackage{guitar}
%\usepackage{harmony,octave,musicography}
%\usepackage{ddphonism}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
%\usepackage{drawmatrix}
\usepackage{xpiano2}% (I rewrote parts of xpiano to add additional functionality)
\keyboardsetup{%
    %color=pianodefault,% color of the note markers
    %single=false,% draw just one octave
    %ext=false,% add a trailing C
    %size=4% size of one white key
    %height=4,% ratio between height and width of white keys
    %ratio=0.75,% ratio between height of white and black keys
    %font=\tiny,% font spec for number
    %numbercolor=black,% color of the numbers
    %10=t,%
    %11=e,%
    %octnum=1%
    numfontfcmd={\bfseries\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans Condensed}},%
    letfontfcmd=numbers,%
    letwhtscale=0.85,%
    letblkscale=0.4%
}%

\usepackage{textstack}

%%% ENCODING AND LANGUAGE %%%
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Bitter}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Roboto}
\setmonofont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=Proportional]{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usepackage[italian,french,american]{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[noglossbreaks,own counter]{covington}

\usepackage[style=mla-new,autocite=footnote,firstlonghand=false,annotation=false,mladraft=true,hyperref=true]{biblatex}


%%% FLOAT/FIGURE %%%%
\usepackage[leftFloats,CaptionAfterwards,varioref,draft]{fltpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%%% CROSSREFS AND TOC %%%
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{varioref}% Load before hyperref
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref} % Recommended load last, but BEFORE glossaries
%\usepackage[hyperref]{hvfloat}
\usepackage[nomain,translate=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage{cleveref}% Load after hyperref
```

Comment: Please post a compilable `MWE` of your document...

Comment: @MadyYuvi It's my senior thesis and the document is quite long, split into multiple files. I suppose you meant only the parts necessary for rendering the tables I'm referring to? Do you need to see all the code regarding the inline musical examples as well, or would some sort of placeholder be sufficient? You'll need lyluatex and the Lilypond file I wrote as well that contains Scheme functions defining a custom notehead stencil.

Comment: Aleast provide your preamble part, i.e., from `\documentclass{...}` to `\begin{document}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi All right, I added it. Let me know if you want to see the contents of any of the other files I mentioned. All of my `\usepackage`s are in that `includes.tex` file, though. Do you also need to see my `latexmkrc`?

Comment: Probably with landscape from the pdflscape package or with sidewaystable from the rotating package?

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for the suggestion! Where would I put the instruction to "landscapify" the float if I used the `pdflscape` package? If I used `sidewaystable`, would I still be able to include multiple `\tabularx`es (preferably some within `\subfigure`s) in that one `sidewaystable`? Or is `sidewaystable` configurable so that you can use `\tabularx` column types in it?

Comment: @the_soo: It yould be a lot easier to help you if you provided a complete and self contained minimal working example that others could use to these out their suggestions. You can definitely use placeholders for the contents of the tables, but `\begin{tabularx}
             % Table 1 content
         \end{tabularx}` is not a valid `tabularx` syntax and will lead to error messages upon compiling.